# Locked out of iPhone5 due to "Activation Required" bug

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios, bug

Yesterday, all of a sudden I started getting "Activation required" on my iPhone5 due to which I just can not login even when I enter my Apple credentials. Exactly this problem - http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1613713.

Trying to follow http://m.imore.com/how-update-ios-7-beta-or-gm-official-release-version to solve it but I just can not get it into DFU mode http://www.imore.com/tip-put-iphone-ipad-dfu-mode. [image]

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1808?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US - "While pressing and holding the Home button down, connect the USB cable to the iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. The device should turn on." - The iPhone does not turn on for me :-/

How do I install 7.2 which has the bug fix?

Comment: There's no such thing as an activation bug. You lapsed and let the beta expire, simple as that. Also, please edit your answer to include your exact question. Do no link to another site for what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use redsn0w to put it in DFU mode. It will help you with the exact timings and the actions to perform.

- [Download redsn0w](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/) (look for the download links at the bottom of the blog post)
- Run redsn0w
- Go to **Extras > Pwned DFU** option
- Follow the step-by-step instructions to put the device in DFU mode
- Running iTunes will prompt you that it has found a device in recovery mode and that you need to restore it first

Although redsn0w is primarily meant for jailbreaking, it is *very useful* for putting an iOS device in DFU mode.

Comment: After I followed all the instructions - It says "Not yet supported on the iPhone5" :-/